# Rails 4.2 - Why is assert_select failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Mozilla is rendering the about link in the footer as href="localhost:3000/about" when it should be rendering as href="/about", but this does not happen when I use chrome.

Any help troubleshooting why my test is failing would be great.

Tests:

```
test "layout links" do
  get root_path
  assert_template 'static_pages/home'
  assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
  assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path #failing
  assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
end
```

after "bundle exec rake test":

```
Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/about"]", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

relevant routes.rb:

```
root             'static_pages#home'
get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
```

view that calls link_to:

```
<li><%= link_to 'About', about_path %></li>
```

note: this is the only failing test, but when I comment out this test then the contact test fails.

edit:

here are my views:

home.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="center jumbotron">
<h1>Sample App</h1>

<p>This is the home page for the railtutorial.org book, ch 3</p>
<%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
</html>
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
        <%= yield %>
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
</body>
```

relevant _footer view with the error:

```
<footer class="footer">
<small>
The <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
by <a href="http://www.michaelhartl.com/">Michael Hartl</a>
</small>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><%= link_to 'About', about_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
  <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: I fixed it! The problem was having the <!DOCTYPE html> and </html> in my home.html.erb file as well as my application.html.erb file. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're using `about_url` in your view instead of `about_path`?

If not then in your test add this line (above the failing line):

```
puts assert_select 'a[href]'
```

That will print all the `<a href` tags from your view, and you should be able to see the about one, and see why the URL isn't what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use about_url instead about_path. It seems that you're using about_url helper in your template, which returns full URL, so test expect to find full url ('wwww.yoursite.com/about') , no relational url ('/about/')

Comment: I tried that and I got a new error message: Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="http://www.example.com/about"]", found 0..

Comment: @userFriendly can you show your template(views/static_pages/home.html.erb)?

Comment: @userFriendly, is your footer being rendered in browser?I noticed that only  links belongs to your footer fail

Comment: thanks for the help the footer was being rendered but incorrectly because there was a </html> rendered before it. It would have been a lot easier to debug had it not rendered at all.